# How to make Segue from TableViewCell image in another View?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

How to make Segue from TableViewCell image in another View? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOGx.png

```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self              action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
     self.CommentAvatarImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [self.CommentAvatarImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void )imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{        
    NSLog(@"AVA Tapped");

}
```

Comment: Google is great: http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/11/02/how-to-trigger-a-segue-programmatically-in-ios/

Comment: @WorkingDev oh really? It does not work for UITableViewCell... Get error:`No visible @interface for 'CommentsCell' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your cell to the view that you want it to segue to when selected. For example, if you want to segue to "nextViewController", then ctrl drag from the respective Table View Cell - Cell in your source Table View to nextViewController. Change the storyboard segue identifier to "nextView".

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];
```

Comment: Get error:`No visible @interface for 'CommentsCell' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'`

Comment: On your storyboard segue (the one going from your tableview to next view), have you put the name of the segue in the identifier?

Comment: @SpaceInvader - I have updated my answer. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: but I need to make Segue by clicking on the image(TableViewCell), and your option will work through didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. So, if you just put "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];" (and note this is different to what I said originally which said sender:sender), what does it say?